# Schedule algorithm for nightly SQL extract of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, data-extraction

I am looking for an algorithm to extract data from one system in to another but on a sliding scale.  Here are the details:

1. Every two weeks, 80 weeks of data needs to be extracted.
2. Extracts take a long time and are resource intensive so we would like to distribute the load of the extract over time.
3. The first 8-12 weeks are the most important and need be updated more often over the two week window.  Data further out can be updated less frequently to the point where the last 40 weeks+ could even just be extracted once every two weeks.
4. Every two weeks, the start date shifts two weeks ahead and so two new weeks are extracted.
5. Extract procedure takes a start and end date (this is already made and should be treated like a black box).  The procedure could be run for multiple date spans in a day if required but contiguous dates are faster than multiple blocks of dates.
6. Extracts blocks should be no smaller than 2 weeks and probably no greater than 16 weeks.  Longer blocks are possible but at 16 weeks are already a significant load to the system.
7. 4 contiguous weeks of data takes about 1 hour approximately. It takes a long time because the data needs to be generated/calculated.
8. Data that is newly extracted replaces the old data for the timespan. No need to merge or diff the data, it is just replaced.
9. This algorithm needs to be built into a SQL job which will handle the daily process (triggered once a day only).

My initial thought was to create a sliding schedule pretty much.  Rotate the first 4 week block every second day and then the second 4 week block every 3 to 4 days.  The rest of the data would be extracted in blocks in smaller chunks over the two week period.

What I am going to do will work but I wanted to spend some time seeing if there might be a better way to approach the problem.  Mainly looking for an algorithm to do the start/end date schedule for the daily extract.

Comment: Do you have a downstream data mart or are you pulling data from an 'online' system?

Comment: @dfb It's all internal.  4 contiguous weeks of data takes about 1 hour approximately.  It takes a long time because the data needs to be generated/calculated and part of the reason we don't want to put to much load on the system doing work.

Comment: @dfb 4 weeks of data is about 1 million rows which isn't that much.  It's generating the rows that takes a long time.